# How to return ALL data members, not just slope and length

Tags: c#

I'm curious as to how (if possible) to return ALL data members in my program by overriding  ToString. The data members are the x and y coordinates as well as the beginning and ending points. Its probably just me missing something small but would appreciate some outside input, thank you.

```
namespace LineMath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point p1 = new Point(10, 5);

            Point p2 = new Point(36, 18);

            LineMath.Program.Point.Line LI1 = new LineMath.Program.Point.Line(p1, p2);


            Console.WriteLine("Line Values");
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine((LI1.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine("----------------");
            Console.WriteLine();

        }

        public class Point
        {
            private double xpoint;
            private double ypoint;

            public Point()
            {
            }

            public Point(double xpointvalue, double ypointvalue)
            {
                xpoint = xpointvalue;
                ypoint = ypointvalue;
            }

            public double X
            {
                get
                {
                    return xpoint;
                }
                set
                {

                }
            }

            public double Y
            {
                get
                {
                    return ypoint;
                }
                set
                {

                }

            }



            public class Line
            {
                private Point bp;
                private Point ep;
                private double li;
                private double sl;

                public Line()
                {
                }


                public Line(Point a, Point b)
                {
                    bp = a;
                    ep = b;

                    li = Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((ep.X - bp.X), 2) + Math.Pow((ep.Y - bp.Y), 2)));
                    sl = (ep.Y - bp.Y) / (ep.X - bp.X);

                }

                public Point BP
                {

                    set
                    {
                    }


                }

                public Point EP
                {

                    set
                    {
                    }

                }

                public double LI
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return li;
                    }

                }

                public double SL
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return sl;
                    }
                }

                public override string ToString()
                {

                    return "Slope = " + sl.ToString("F2") + "\n" + "\n" + "Length = " + li.ToString("F2");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what object are you referring to?

Comment: Of course it's possible to return anything and everything you want by overriding ToString(). Just return as much data as you want in your overriden method.

Comment: @user3508959, You cannot paste a multiline string into a comment. Please update your question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can return more than value from a method by either using `out` parameters or creating a new data structure (a `struct` or `class`) to hold your return values. e.g.

```
private void GetXYBeginEnd(int a, int b, out int x, out int y, out int begin, out int end)
{
    // assign your out params in here
}
```

OR:

```
class CalcResult
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Begin { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
}

private CalcResult GetXYBeginEnd(int a, int b, out int x, out int y, out int begin, out int end)
{
    // do stuff
    return new CalcResult { X = 23, Y = 54, Begin = 45, End = 98 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of ToString() is to provide a string representation of an object instance that is in some way meaningful to you the programmer (often for debugging), or the users of your program.

You have access to all of the fields, properties and methods of the class and can create whatever string representation is meaningful to you from those.

> return ALL data members in my program

A *program* typically consists of more than one class.  ToString() acts on a given instance of a given class, not "an entire program".  You may need to clarify what you mean by that part of your question.

If you want to return the *data*, and if you expect to do something with that data (besides display it), you should not use ToString() for that purpose.

**UPDATE** (based on your edit)

Look at the extra line I added.  It shows one way to include your property BP.  You can extend that for any other properties.  Note too that you are using "\n\n" but probably mean "\r\n" for Windows environments.  You can use Environment.NewLine to have the runtime handle the correct newline codes for you.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Slope = " + sl.ToString("F2") + "\n" + "\n" + "Length = " + li.ToString("F2")
        Environment.NewLine + " BP (" + BP.X + ", " + BP.Y + ")";
}
```

Comment: I put in what I have so far up above

Comment: Updated my answer based on that

Comment: Its just for a Console program

Answer (score 0):

Place a formula for slope and length, as value for SL and LI respectively

```
public double SL
{
    get
    {
        if(bp == null || ep == null)
            sl = 0.0;
        else
            //Formula for slope of a line
            sl = (ep.Y - bp.Y) / (ep.X - bp.X);
        return sl;
    }
}

public double LI
{
    get
    {
        //Use Euclidean distance to get length of line
        if(bp == null || ep == null)
            li = 0.0;
        else
            li =  Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(bp.X - ep.X, 2) + Math.Pow(bp.Y - ep.Y, 2));
        return li;
    }
}

public override string ToString()
{
    //Something like this
    return "Line1\nBegin Point: (" + bp.X + ", " + bp.Y + ")\nEnd Point: (" + ep.X + ", " + ep.Y + ")\n\nSlope = " + sl.ToString("F2") + "\n\n" + "Length = " + li.ToString("F2");
}
```